# Regex pattern on different length strings

Tags: regex

I need to extract some data from a string like:

```
AAA, BBB, (CCC), DDD
```

With this expression I can extract any group I want:

```
(.*)(, )(.*)(, )(.*)(, )(.*)
$1
```

My problem is, that sometimes the string only has 5 groups instead of 7 and looks like:

```
AAA, BBB, (CCC)
```

In this case my expression will not work because there is no match.

Any ideas how to write an expression to work with both types of strings?

Comment: why don't you simply split it by commas?

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is what I tried to split by commas. But I have to situation where I have 3 commas, and the 4 commas version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is comma-delimited, you'd want to use a CSV parser for your programming language. Otherwise, you can turn your capturing groups to `[^,]` and make groups optional with `?`:

```
([^,]*)(, )([^,]*)(, )([^,]*)(, )?([^,]*)?
```

Have a look at the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pK9hF8/1)

Answer (score -1):

You can make a group itself repeat. This is a fairly typical regex pattern.

```
(.*)(,.*)*
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Basically I need that regex uses the "longer" pattern if that matches and the shorter if that is the matching one.
( .*)(, )(.*)(, )(.*)(, )(.*) long
(.*)(, )(.*)(, )(.*) short